# HMVC internal/external requests and routes?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url-routing, hmvc

I think I understand the concept of HMVC after reading this question and answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220480/hmvc-and-database-connections; an extract from an answer is below:

> Let's assume you want to have a view that enables a user to make a
>   comment to a blog post. You would have fields for name, e-mail, title
>   and comment, but you also want to have a field country displayed as a
>   dropdown. In the action that displays this view you would make a
>   database query that loads the countries and then populate that
>   dropdown. Which is ok, but it forces you to duplicate the query and
>   the view required to display the countries if you need it in another
>   part of your application. A better approach would be to create
>   separate controller for countries with an action that returns a view
>   with the dropdown and then render that action whenever you need to
>   show a list of countries.

What I cannot wrap my head around is that if I can internally request a controller/model/view which just displays a widget (e.g. a country select box), doesn't that mean that by accessing that url from a browser will also just show that view?

How is this managed in HMVC, are routes defined as internal/external only, so matching an internal route with an external request would show a 404 page?

Is this generally how it is done and is the HMVC description/definition above satisfiable with the general use case of it in most web applications?

Comment: You can just not to attach the controller to any routes, and call it internally directly in other controllers, so nobody will see it externally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the output of a sub-request in the browser shouldn't be a problem, so I wouldn't bother, especially that those URLs are not known by the user and it's safe to output the widgets separately.

Despite the above, you could, as @deceze mentionned, not attach those controllers to any routes. If you have a "default" route (matching all requests), then you would have to disable it.